# Show navbar on top of an image in bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I am working on a portfolio website in flask, python, HTML, CSS. However, I have encountered what seems like a simple error but I can't solve it.

I want the navbar to be on top of the background image that I'm using from Unsplash. The background picture is also showing up on all the other pages too. I don't want that. All I want is, a home page with the background image and the navbar being on top of it so that it looks good. The contact page, portfolio, and about should have their own content and it should not display the home image.

This is what I mean. I want the home page to be similar to this site and when browsing other images it should display its content (http://template-shutter.webflow.io/photographers)

http://template-shutter.webflow.io/

Here is my template code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jainam's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="bgimg navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">First LastName</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('about')}}">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('portfolio')}}">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('contact')}}">Contact</a>
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% extends "template.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bgimg {
  min-height: 600px;  
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478515463067-d20f52aace26?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=968&q=80');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar{
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position of `navbar` as `relative` instead of using `absolute`

```
 .navbar{
     position:relative;
     z-index:1;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: @user3002108 check this

Comment: I did. it doesn't work. It's in the center of the image and when I browse other pages, the image still shows up.